# What is the difference between crit runes?

Tags: league-of-legends

i just realised that there are 2 Crit Quintessences, 1: + 4,46% crit damage AND 2: 1,86% crit damage

AND both with the same price of 1025 IP.

Can anyone explain this? why would someone ever buy the 1,86 crit, when you cant get the double, with the same price.

Answer (score 9):

That might be because the 1.86% is critical CHANCE, not damage. It raises the probability you will score a critical hit. The other rune raises the damage inflicted by a critical hit. Normally they deal 200% damage, but with a Critical Damage Quintessence, it will deal 204.46% of the attack's damage.

Source: [LoL wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Quintessence)

Comment: bah, beat me to it, was nearly done writing the same :)

Comment: Well, if you can phrase and explain it better, you can still take the lead. :-)

Comment: I don't play league, but I'm confused on your math here.. It's a 1.86% crit chance, but then you say instead of 200% damage crits will do 201.86 damage. Did you mean to add the 4.46%? and would it really be additive or `originalChance*((100+4.46)/100)`?

Comment: totalDamage = damage * 2.0446;//If it crits

Answer (score 0):

You start off with a 0% chance to crit.  Items and runes can increase the chance.  Adding a crit % quint adds a 1.86% chance to crit.

That's not the end of it, however: if you have a crit chance better than 0%, *each failure to crit improves your crit chance*. This is why you will sometimes see someone run even a single crit chance mark in their rune pages.